# RegEx for 301 redirects to change path AND remove a string

Tags: rewrite, regex, 301-redirect, url

I am looking for an RegEX redirect rule to redirect the image file locations to a new location, whilst also removing part of the original url which is the name of the image

OLD URL:

```
/components/com_mijoshop/opencart/image/cache/catalog/ecom2/GM815-365x365.jpg
```

NEW URL:

```
/wp-content/uploads/nc/catalog/ecom2/GM815.jpg
```

So I need to change the directory path AND remove the ‘-365x365’ part of the url.

I can remove the part of the image name with the following, but unsure how to also change the path:

```
/(?'path'.*)-365x365.jpg  /[path].jpg
```

Comment: What is the environment where you are using the regex?

Comment: It’s Wordpress, a redirect plugin. We migrated from a really old Joomla site and we have thousands of image urls that have changed that I would like to put 301s on.

Comment: Please add link to the plugin to the question, so that we can check the documentation. Without seeing documentation, an answer cannot be given.

Comment: Please see link to the plugin documentation.  If you could help it would be very much appreciated. 

https://docs.wp301redirects.com/article/307-regex-redirects-recipes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
/components/com_mijoshop/opencart/image/cache/(?'path'.*)-365x365.jpg /wp-content/uploads/nc/[path].jpg
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked perfectly!